# export txt file with all parameter values during the report execution

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I've developed one report in Report Builder 3.0 , report server being  SRSS 2008 R2. This report has one report parameter named id_product. There are two data sets available. One data set  is for populating the report table.  In the second data set I'm trying to export the id_product. The below query works fine only for single valued parameter id_product, this query being used in the second data set   Report pops-up an error when trying to run the report for multiple products at the same time. I looked in SQL Profiler and it seems like inserting the parameter values in the global temporary table is not possible using the current code.

I'm aware of the VB Expression named Join but in such case I'm not sure if I can use it. It would be great if I can use this kind of expression. This way I would not create the data set anymore.

Current query:

```
    drop table ##SelectedValues
    create table ##SelectedValues(id_product nvarchar(max))
    insert into ##SelectedValues(@id_product) 
    exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select ''id_product'' 
    union all select * from ##SelectedValues" queryout "G:\Report\sqloutput.csv" -c -T -t'
```

Input: ProductId parameter values : 12, 16, 20

Desired output in csv:

id_product

12

16

20

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a split function that parses the comma delimited string to table rows, or you can use my favorite, dynamic sql! :)

```
if object_id('tempdb..#SelectedValues') is not null
    drop table #SelectedValues
create table #SelectedValues(id_product nvarchar(max))
declare @id_product nvarchar(max),@sql nvarchar(max)
set @id_product = '12, 16, 20'
set @sql = 
    'select ''' + replace(@id_product,', ',''' union all select ''') + ''''
insert into #SelectedValues(id_product) exec(@sql)
select * from #SelectedValues
```